# Connect to SQL Server from CakePHP 3 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: php, sql-server, cakephp, pdo, cakephp-3.0

My setup was working on Windows but I recently switched to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and now it won't connect. When I load a page where I need to talk to SQL Server, I get this error:

> Database driver Cake\Database\Driver\Sqlserver cannot be used due to a
>   missing PHP extension or unmet dependency

It is obvious that CakePHP can't find the SQL Server PDO driver.

I found many old tutorials to help me but I took the most recent (I want absolutely to be able to use PDO with my CakePHP website). [This is the tutorial I followed](http://onefinepub.com/2013/03/ms-sql-odbc-ubuntu/).

Using the terminal, I can access the database with this command

```
sqlcmd -S my.sql.server.com -U username
```

What do I need to do to connect to this sql server database from my ubuntu install with CakePHP 3.x?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: My server is using php

Comment: `It is obvious that CakePHP can't find the SQL Server PDO driver` - have you tried to install it? If _php_ can't connect to the db, CakePHP won't be able to either.

Comment: My php.ini contains the `pdo_odbc.connection_pooling=strict` statement. I didn't load any php extension.

Comment: I installed the driver. This driver allow me to use the sqlcmd utility. Maybe I need another php module?

Comment: My mistake on odbc in short: to use ODBC you need to use a ODBC driver(.php), not sqlserver(.php). CakePHP's sql server driver [is for using PDO_SQLSRV](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Database/Driver/Sqlserver.php#L69); If you need to use ODBC, [there isn't one in the core](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tree/master/src/Database/Driver).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update (October 17th 2016):

Microsoft recently released a [preview version](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql) (on their msphpsql repo) of **pdo_sqlsrv** and **sqlsrv** for **Linux**. It worked successfully for me on a Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (Xenial Xerus) virtual machine running php7.

---

### Original answer:

As @AD7six said:

> CakePHP's sql server driver is for using PDO_SQLSRV; If you need to use ODBC, there isn't one in the core.

**PDO_SQLSRV** is working if you are on **Windows**. CakePHP has a driver that support it natively.

If you want to talk to a SQL Server Database from **Linux**, you have to use the **ODBC driver**. You can install the driver using [this tutorial](http://onefinepub.com/2013/03/ms-sql-odbc-ubuntu/) which helped me a lot. After that, you will be able to connect to your database using PDO (not CakePHP):

```
try {
  $query = new PDO(
    "odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Database=[Database name]; Server=[Hosame]",
    "[Username]", 
    "[Password]");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Thanks everybody for your help. It could be great to find/code a CakePHP 3 database driver for odbc.

Answer (score 1):

The new version of CakePHP supports PDO-sqlsrv which is new the MS driver that supports PHP 7 and higher.

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php

It also allows you to connect to Azure. Example:

//Establishes the connection
     $conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=$serverName ; Database = $database", $uid, $pwd);